# Extract unique pixel values from raster in geemap with overlapping points

Tags: python, raster, google-earth-engine, geemap

I'm extracting band values from a Landsat raster image using the `extract_values_to_points()` function in geemap. I have a feature class with latitudes and longitudes for each sampling point, however, in several cases points are located within the same pixel (see image below).

[image: Landsat image with multiple sampling points in individual pixels]

I would like to extract band values from the raster only once per pixel, as opposed to having multiple points with identical band values. If possible, I'd like to try extracting band values for a randomly selected sampling point within each pixel, while excluding other sampling points within that same pixel.

Currently, my code is simply `geemap.extract_values_to_points(fc_coords, image, out_csv)`, where fc_coords is the list of lat/long values. Is there any way to achieve this in geemap?